# How should I organize R package code and documentation when method functions share common arguments?

Tags: r, documentation, organization

Let's say I'm writing an R package that contains the function `foo`, which has methods for two classes `typea` and `typeb`. My understanding is that I would include the following in my package script files:

```
foo <- function(...) UseMethod("foo")

foo.typeA <- function(x, common.arg, unique.argA) {
     #Things foo does with typeA objects
}
foo.typeB <- function(x, common.arg, unique.argB) {
     #Things foo does with typeB objects
}
```

Assume I want to have separate documentation pages for each method. Here, the documentation for `common.arg` appears on the pages for both `foo.typeA` and `foo.typeB`. This can be unwieldy if I add another argument common to both functions or if I want to update the documentation for `common.arg`.

Does it make sense to instead have my functions be the following:

```
foo <- function(..., common.arg) UseMethod("foo")

foo.typeA <- function(x, unique.argA, ...) {
     #Things foo does with typeA objects
}
foo.typeB <- function(x, unique.argB, ...) {
     #Things foo does with typeB objects
}
```

and then only have the documentation for `common.arg` on the `foo` page? If I want to refer to `common.arg` in the method functions, do I have to extract it from the `...` (e.g., with `args <- list(...)`), or can I call it by name as if it were an argument directly to the method functions?

Also, this was a toy example; my actual problem involves many more methods and many more common arguments. Also, this is partly about documentation but also about general code organization. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using `roxygen`? If so maybe look at `@template` or `@inheritParams`. If not, you're probably going to want to look at something to autogenerate such documentation files because there's no such way to do that with simple Rd syntax.

Comment: I'm not. I'm hoping to avoid autogenerating documentation by consolidating documentation. Maybe I do have to learn `roxygen`. My biggest problem with it is that all the `roxygen` code appears in all of your functions files.

Comment: If you use roxygen, you can [reuse bits of documentation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#dry2). And for documentation purposes repeating yourself can never hurt. You need to look from the perspective of someone who looks for the first time at your objects and wonders how to use them. What is logical for you is often not logical to someone else.